# How to pass column names in a SQL query as parameters using report builder 3.0

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0

I am using "Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder 3.0" on "SQL Server Reporting Services 2012".

From a main report main.rdl I am calling a drillthrough report detail.rdl

The main.rdl report has a table and each text box of this table is clickable and drillthrough action. When user clicks on any text box the detail.rdl report is called. One parameter that is passed to detail.rdl report is used as a column name in the SQL. This SQL fetches data needed for detail.rdl report

When I run the SQL query for detail.rdl report that is built using parameters, it is not showing any error but doesn't fetch any data either. I think what is happening is that as the parameter has data type Text, it's replaced in SQL with quotes which might be causing it not to fetch any data.

When I run the same SQL directly on DB after replacing the column name with parameter value (without quotes) it does fetch data.

Is there any specific way to pass parameters that will be used as column names that I am missing here?

SQL that I am trying from report builder:

```
SELECT
  table_name.column1
  ,table_name.column21
  ,table_name.column15
  ,table_name.column6
  ,table_name.column9
  ,table_name.column2
  ,table_name.column19
  ,@column --the value in this variable is an existing column name from table table_name
FROM
  table_name
WHERE
  table_name.column1 LIKE @company
  AND table_name.column21 LIKE @platform
  AND (@column is null OR @column = '' OR @column = 'N/A' OR @column = 'Unknown');--I want to use same variable here as well
```

**UPDATE:**
I was able to get the SQL working by adding

```
DECLARE @company varchar(10)
SET @company = ''company_name''
DECLARE @platform varchar(10)
SET @platform = ''platform_name''
```

after the line

```
SET @SQL =
'
```

Unfortunately "Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder 3.0" is not able to execute this SQL as it asks for value of variable @SQL even though it's value is defined. I did try Declaring and setting the value of @SQL in same line as:

```
DECLARE @SQL varchar(5000) = 'DECLARE @company varchar(10)
```

But report builder still asks for value of @SQL and report doesn't run :-(

Comment: The issue is my fault. Parameter names are case sensitive so make sure it reads '@SQL' everywhere, the last statement had it as "@sql'. SSRS may have also also added an '@sql' parameter in the designer,if so you can safely remove this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell what the problem is without seeing your code but you can't just swap a string in the SQL like (I think) you are trying to do.

To test your SQL just do something simple in Management Studio like

```
DECLARE @MyParm varchar(256) = 'myColumnName'
SELECT *, @MyParm FROM myTable
```

This will return all columns from MyTable, plus a string value of 'myColumnName' as the final column.

If this is what you are trying to do then you'll probably need to change your SQL to use dynamic SQL, something like this.

```
DECLARE @MyParm varchar(256) = 'myCOlumnName'
DECLARE @SQL varchar(max)

SET @SQL = 'SELECT *, ' + @MyParm + ' FROM myTable'

EXEC (@SQL)
```

If I've got this completely wrong, please post some sample code so we can see what you are attempting.

**EDIT: here is a specific answer based on your sample code**

```
DECLARE @Column sysname = 'Column999'
DECLARE @SQL varchar(max)

SET @SQL = 
'SELECT 
    table_name.column1 ,table_name.column21 ,table_name.column15 ,table_name.column6 
    ,table_name.column9 ,table_name.column2 ,table_name.column19 
    ,' + @column + 
    ' FROM table_name 
    WHERE table_name.company LIKE @company 
        AND table_name.platform LIKE @platform 
        AND (' + @column + ' is null OR ' + @column + ' = '''' OR ' + @column + ' = ''N/A'' OR ' + @column + ' = ''Unknown'')'

-- uncomment below to check SQL statement is correct
--print @sql

-- exec the SQL statement
exec (@sql)
```

As it stands, this will execute the following sql

```
SELECT 
    table_name.column1 ,table_name.column21 ,table_name.column15 ,table_name.column6 
    ,table_name.column9 ,table_name.column2 ,table_name.column19 
    ,Column999 FROM table_name 
    WHERE table_name.company LIKE @company 
        AND table_name.platform LIKE @platform 
        AND (Column999 is null OR Column999 = '' OR Column999 = 'N/A' OR Column999 = 'Unknown')
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Here is what I am trying to do: `SELECT
  table_name.column1
  ,table_name.column21
  ,table_name.column15
  ,table_name.column6
  ,table_name.column9
  ,table_name.column2
  ,table_name.column19
  ,@column --the value in this variable is an existing column name from table table_name
FROM
  table_name
WHERE
  table_name.company LIKE @company
  AND table_name.platform LIKE @platform
  AND (@column is null OR @column = '' OR @column = 'N/A' OR @column = 'Unknown');--I want to use same variable here as well`

Comment: I've edited my answer to match your specific example

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but how can I declare and set @company and @platform? I have tried like `DECLARE @company varchar(10) = 'company_name'` and `DECLARE @platform varchar(10) = 'platform_name'` after the line `DECLARE @Column sysname = 'Column999'` but the query fails with error: Must declare the scalar variable "@company". I tried declaring and setting on separate lines but still get same error.

Comment: Updated my question with your suggested solution. Unfortunately "Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder 3.0" doesn't work with this SQL. So I am still looking for other resources/options.

Comment: The issue is my fault. Parameter names are case sensitive so make sure it reads '@SQL' everywhere, the last statement had it as "@sql'. SSRS may have also also added an '@sql' parameter in the designer,if so you can safely remove this.

Comment: **NOTE** You should not declare the variables in the SQL statement if they are being passed in from SSRS as parameters. I included `@column` so you could test the sql. For example, if `@column` is a parameter name in your report design, you should comment out the `DECLARE @Column sysname = 'Column999'` line of code.

Comment: All three variables @column, @company and @platform are parameters passed from SSRS. Only difference is @column needs to be used as column name while other two as string. I tried commenting out `DECLARE @column sysname = 'Column999'` and it gives error as: An error occurred while executing the query. 
Incorrect syntax near '@company'. (Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder) I can't figure out what is wrong in the SQL from error message. It's not very infomative

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143987/discussion-between-300-and-alan-schofield).

Comment: I'm based in the UK so contact me during working hours here and we'll get you sorted out